# check if condition and append string multiple times

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation

Below is the array assigned to the variable **$value**

```
Array
(
    [colname] => leadnumber
    [tabname] => lead
    [uitypeid] => 14
    [fieldname] => leadnumber
    [filedlabel] => Lead Number
    [readmode] => Yes
    [mandmode] => No
    [fieldmode] => Yes
    [fieldseq] => 1
    -----
    ----
)
```

What I need.
I have to check the value for each item and append like below.

```
$rule = "required|unique|read|tabname|lorem|ipsum|etc.."
```

I have done like below.

```
if($value['mandmode'] == "No"){
    $rule = 'trim';
}
if($value['modfieldunique'] == "No"){
    $rule = $rule.'|unique';
}
if($value['readmode'] == "No"){
    $rule = $rule.'|read';
}
```

My question is I have many conditions like these to check for each value before appending it to variable. If I do So the script running time increases. Is there a better way to get the result in that format?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the concept? indices, values appended...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can structure the rules into an array, like this

```
$referenceRules = [
    "manmode"           => "trim",
    "modfieldunique"    => "unique",
    "readmode"          => "read"
];
```

Then iterate over your array and check which elements match the rules.
The `if` clause checks if the current key is also a key of the `referenceRules` array `and` if the current value is "No".
Assuming you are checking **all** elements to match "No".

```
$rules = [];

foreach($array as $key => $value){

    if (in_array($key,array_keys($referenceRules)) and $value == "No"){

        print $key . ":" . $value . PHP_EOL;    
        $rules[] = $referenceRules[$key];

    }

}
```

Using this array

```
$array = [
    "colname" => "leadnumber",
    "tabname" => "lead",
    "uitypeid" => 14,
    "fieldname" => "leadnumber",
    "filedlabel" => "Lead Number",
    "readmode" => "No",
    "manmode" => "No",  // I changed the key here to match your rules
    "fieldmode" => "Yes",
    "fieldseq" => 1
];
```

The above will output

```
readmode:No
manmode:No
```

At the end simply `implode` the `$rules` array to output the string you need

```
$ruleString = implode("|",$rules);
print $ruleString;
```

This will output

```
read|trim
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply take an array of rules.

And append values to it depending upon conditions.

In the end, we will get only required rules as array elements.

Now, simply append all of them with `|`.

**Done**

**Code:**

```
<?php
$rules = array();
if ($value['mandmode'] == "No"){
 $rules[] = 'trim';
}
if ($value['modfieldunique'] == "No"){
 $rules[] = 'unique';
}
if ($value['readmode'] == "No"){
 $rules[] = 'read';
}
$rule = ! empty($rules) ? implode('|', $rules) : '';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below looping:

```
$rule = '';
foreach($value as $elementKey => $elementValue)
{
    switch($elementKey)
    {
        case "mandmode":
            if($elementValue == 'no')
                $rule .= 'trim|';
        break;

        case "modfieldunique":
            if($elementValue == 'no')
                $rule .= 'unique|';
        break;

        case "readmode":
        case "XYZ":         //You can add more conditions as requirement
            if($elementValue == 'no')
                $rule .= 'read|';
        break;
    }
}

$rule = substr($rule,0,-1);
```

You can add multiple cases where same conditions are possible... Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
// Take arrays from AlexAndrei answer
$referenceRules = [
    "manmode"           => "trim",
    "modfieldunique"    => "unique",
    "readmode"          => "read"
];
$array = [
    "colname" => "leadnumber",
    "tabname" => "lead",
    "uitypeid" => 14,
    "fieldname" => "leadnumber",
    "filedlabel" => "Lead Number",
    "readmode" => "No",
    "manmode" => "No",  // I changed the key here to match your rules
    "fieldmode" => "Yes",
    "fieldseq" => 1
];   
// Save only those which equal No
$temp = array_filter($array, function($i) { return $i === "No"; });
// Take corresponding itemms from referenceRules array
$temp = array_intersect_key($referenceRules, $temp);
// Make string
echo implode('|', $temp); // trim|read
```

[demo](https://eval.in/567201)